# Using a 2nd UV Set with SCNGeometry

Tags: ios, scenekit, normals

I want to add a normal mapping to an `SCNGeometry`. I have a normal-map image (PNG) and a second set of UV coordinates, injected as `GeometrySource`.

My favourite solution to this, if possible, would be to add a shader modifier to the affected geometries and this way avoid to clone the--by definition--geometry-independent materials for each geometry that has a normal map.

So, can anyone tell me please, if it is possible to manipulate the normals based on a secondary texture-coordinate set (*) and an image via geometry-bound Shader Modifiers. If so, any sniplets, etc. would greatly by appreciated.

Metal shader code would be preferred over `OpenGL` shader code.

Thx in advance,

Ekki

(*) If access to this isn't possible, I would suggest to use a currently unused vertex semantics for this and take the information from there.

Here's the screenshot of the in-process version (linked in the comments):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`SCNMaterialProperty` has a [`mappingChannel`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnmaterialproperty/1395405-mappingchannel) property that lets you specify which texture coordinates source should be used for the mapping.

Is there a shortcoming that makes you want to use a shader modifier instead?

Comment: Hi, didn't know about the mappingChannel. So I did think it needs a shader/shader modifier to implement this. Will do research on this. Would be just great if this solves my issue. Thx so far...

Comment: The index is relative to the Texture Coordinates GeometrySources-no to the GeometrySources at all, right? I'm using VertexAttribute semantics "TextureCoordinate" (as predefined on MDL side) to pass the 2nd UV set over to SCNGeometry, which works and it's even recognized as texture coordinates...

Comment: it's starting to work! but there seems to be an issue in the vertical direction. This is surely a little bit off-topic but maybe you could have a look anyway and some comment? [link](http://ig2.intelligentgraphics.biz/owncloud/index.php/s/DGfKpu6eR1UaNw3)

Comment: about the issue... had to change the V coordinate from v to (1 - v) - that solved the problem. Thx again.